# SwiftMailer, PhpMailer, etc: Difference between mail() and sendmail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, sendmail, swiftmailer

I often read that PHP's **mail()**-Function uses **sendmail** internally.

So why do Mail-Libraries like SwiftMailer, PhpMailer, etc give us the chance to CHOOSE between **mail()** and **sendmail**?

Isn't it the same thing?

Never heard anyone saying that it's NOT the same thing!

Please help, 'cause I'm really confused about that!

Comment: mail() is primary for single email (opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email you send) where as sendmail() is more for batch processes (many)

Answer (score 4):

On unix-like systems, `mail()` does indeed use sendmail, but this is not the case on Windows (which doesn't have sendmail at all, so `mail()` instead sends through SMTP).

The real benefit of Swiftmailer, et al., is that they provide an OOP wrapper around sending email, so that your email content generation is abstracted (properly generating MIME envelopes and getting headers correct can be tricky, especially when user input requires escaping), and also the actual transport mechanism is abstracted as well (so you could replace an SMTP or sendmail transport with a custom transport using a mail provider's API without having to change all your code).

Answer (score 1):

A typical `sendmail` binary (e.g. one from postfix), even if called via PHP's `mail` function, opens a synchronous connection to localhost and conducts a full SMTP transaction. This can mean that it's actually *slower* than using SMTP directly - and in fact [the postfix docs recommend using SMTP to localhost](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#mailing_tips) in preference to sendmail if you're looking for performance. In particular you can benefit from keepalive when sending lots of messages by using SMTP.

One trick is that you can pass an additional parameter to sendmail (specifically `-O DeliveryMode=b`) to tell it to operate asynchronously, in which case it returns immediately, making your mail sending much more responsive, but because PHP isn't set up to handle that, you lose the ability to handle errors that may occur so this is not recommended. You can use this either by calling the sendmail binary yourself with those options, or by passing it in the `$additional_parameters` parameter.

Generally there isn't really any difference between mail and sendmail options in PHPMailer, though it might possibly be useful if you want to use a sendmail binary other than the one that PHP is set to use.

Comment: OHHH NOOO you confuse posrtfix with sendmail and sending emails

Comment: Not at all. I do know the difference, and this answer addresses the question directly. I wouldn't put much stock in your opinion given the answer you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Ussualy i use mail() function. But sometimes i need to send email via non-local SMTP server. Sure i can change setting in php.ini, but i think better is use some email library.  My choise is the Swift Mailer.

Comment: Is it really possible to configure php.ini to use a non-local SMTP (like GMail)?? I always used sendmail for this. Is it really possible WITHOUT sendmail? If yes: Where (within php.ini) should i place username, password and ssl/tls. The section [mail function] in Php.ini does not offer things like that.

Comment: I use Windows server. This option works good

    [mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    SMTP = mail.yourserver.com
    smtp_port = 25
    auth_username = smtp-username
    auth_password = smtp-password
    sendmail_from = you@yourserver.com